# How can Dart language be used in a website today?

Tags: javascript, dart

Is there a Javascript based interpreter it can run on, similar to CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the code is compiled to Javascript before it is made available, sort of like Google Web Toolkit.

see: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/technical-overview/index.html

And apparently you can use Dart to do server-side code as well.

Comment: I haven't looked yet, but I expect the server-side code also translates into Javascript which runs on V8.

Comment: @Greg, no there is a native VM that runs Dart directly.

Comment: The [Dart wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_%28programming_language%29) suggests otherwise, that there will definitely be a native VM for Dart. This is the goal of Dart - to oust Javascript by integrating native engines in the browser and presumably on the server as well. There would be no reason for Google to not use a native VM.

Answer (score 2):

There is a script provided 'htmlconverter.py' which will compile an html file (plus any .dart and .css it uses) into an html file with embedded javascript. It even inlines any images referenced from the css so you can end up with a single html file with all assets included.

If you compile the hello world sample with this converter the output is about a 200k html file (with --optimize) or about 10MB with the default debug compilation. That probably means you get something usable if it's an actual app but not so good for dropping small snippets into a page.

Answer (score 1):

Answer that is current as of Dec. 2013: Use the `dart2js` compiler to convert Dart code to JavaScript.

Sample usage:

```
dart2js --out=foo.js foo.dart
```

You can [read more about dart2js](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart2js.html) on dartlang.org.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlconvert.py, or you can use DartC to compile you dart programs to a single *myprogram.dart*.js files and include that in html script tags.

Answer (score 0):

[Dart Editor binaries](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/getting-started/editor/) are now available for Windows, Mac, and Linux:

> Dart Editor is a lightweight, open-source editor based on Eclipse components. In addition to editing Dart programs, **you can use Dart Editor to invoke the Dart-to-JavaScript compiler and launch Dart-based web apps**. Get started with the [Dart Editor tutorial](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/getting-started/editor/), where you can download the continuous or integration builds.